# ASP.NET page cannot be displayed error while running in the debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, localhost

My application was running fine in the debug mode, however, out of the blue (without changing any web.config or global.asax.cs file) One of the pages stopped loading, and it started giving me a "page cannot be displayed" error.

I have tried everything suggested in the following links:

[How to fix "This page can't be displayed" error in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706173/how-to-fix-this-page-cant-be-displayed-error-in-asp-net)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1934509.aspx?How+do+I+fix+This+page+can+t+be+displayed+error+in+asp+net+c+

What's baffling is that it is not even connected to any internet, I am trying to debug my application on local host... Is there something I have missed or need to check for this particular error to go away. I have no content in global.asax.cs and my customerrors mode is 'off'. What else can lead to this error.

Comment: You are debugging via IIS Express or standard IIS?

Comment: I find that when ASP.NET starts acting up, especially without having changed any settings, more often than not you can fix it by restarting Visual Studio

Comment: @Kai I have done it a ton of times, I have run the code in different machines as well but it is still acting up :(

Comment: @jjczopek, I am running it in the debug mode...Will IIS be a part of it? if yes, I don't know how to check that

Comment: Have you checked the IIS port listed in your project is the same port running as displayed in the browser?

Comment: I haven't hosted it at all, just f5 (debug mode) run

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer to this one, basically, the page that was not loading had an upload option, which(uploadbtn_click) thereafter was  redirecting to the "page cannot be displayed" error page.

The reason was that when we run the code in debug mode, Visual Studio launches its own version of IIS and self-hosts the site to run temporarily. However, it doesn't allow a lot of memory for upload/download. Which is why this error.

Hence, this problem would go away if we host the file in IIS, because there we get a default of 50 MB for such actions.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem - in web.config file in  section add next parameter :
 
2097152 = 2G